# Google Map POI items with Location finder text box and Search results

Tags: sxa

I tried implementing location finder using https://michaellwest.blogspot.in/2016/10/build-location-finder-search-using-sxa.html and able to implement the functionality with minor issues:

1. If I am assigning POI item on map date item then after clicking on POI item on MAP, it’s showing the details. In this case while searching any place using Location Finder/Search Results component, it will show all the details not specific POI item

   Assign POI item to MAP:
   [image: Assign POI item to MAP]
   [image]
2. If I am not assigning POI item on map date item then after clicking on POI item on MAP, it’s not showing the details and showing error on console (400 bad request). In this case while searching any place using Location Finder/Search Results component, it will narrow down the result and show particular POI item on MAP:

   POI items not assigned to MAP:
   [image]

   [image]

   400 bad request url : http://site//sxa/geoVariants/1ad82bbf-4d55-4dbd-b635-b68cf2171002/ae69e57b-da98-4bd5-b889-477448d61139/13.0826802,80.27071840000008/undefined&site=null

   ```
   Is there any pointers to resolve above issue, so that after clicking on POI item, it will show the details of POI item?
   ```

Comment: That should work OOTB without any problems. Check out this link for an example https://michaellwest.blogspot.com/2016/10/build-location-finder-search-using-sxa.html.

Comment: I tried this post of yours but it's showing distance from searched to POI items and map not showing matched items.

Comment: Did you include a search box component?

Comment: I used the location finder text box not search text box. Shall I use Search text box instead of location finder text box?

Comment: Try a combination of both.

Comment: Ok. I will try.

Comment: I was able to test your scenario and I found an issue with clicking on the POI. I've already fixed it but I cannot tell you right now if this will make into 1.7.

Answer (score 2):

Just like Michel wrote - it's possible out of the box in SXA. You don't need to drop Search Box rendering. Take a look below:

[image]

If out would like to have auto-complete from Google in your Location Finder you need to provide the number of options you want to see:

[image]

Remember also about providing Google (or Bing - it depends on what you want to use) key in `/sitecore/content/Tenant/Site/Settings/Maps Provider` item.

Comment: Any inputs on query.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of time right now. I'll look at this tomorrow.